# please describe how to query a quickbooks invoice using the Quickbooks PHP SDK for line items containing a specific service date

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I need to retrieve all service dates from sales detail line items on a quickbooks invoice using PHP.

I can retrieve the invoice, the lines, but not the service date...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DocNumber ='".$docNumber."'";
$invoices = $InvoiceService->query($Context, $realm, $sql);
$Line = $invoices[0]->getLine(0);
$Detail = $Line->getSalesItemLineDetail();

and $Detail, when using  var_dump($Detail->getServiceDate()); 

returns null.

but a var_dump shows $Detail to be:

bject(QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail)#90 (1) {
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["ItemRef"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "{-35}"
    }
    ["ItemRef_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "00008"
    }
    ["UnitPrice"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "2.86"
    }
    ["Qty"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["TaxCodeRef"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "{-6}"
    }
    ["ServiceDate"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2018-06-01"
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that $Line->getDetailType() == 'SalesItemLineDetail', then 
using the get method for the SalesItemLineDetail will return an object that contains the getServiceDate() method and that will return the proper value.

```
if ($Line->getDetailType() == 'SalesItemLineDetail') {
  $Detail = $Line->getSalesItemLineDetail();
  echo $Detail->getServiceDate();
}
```